# Does the electron cloud possess its own angular momentum analogous to classical objects

Tags: quantum-mechanics

In quantum mechanics, electrons are often described by probability distributions known as electron clouds, representing the likelihood of finding an electron in a particular region around an atom's nucleus. While individual electrons possess intrinsic angular momentum, often referred to as spin, the question arises whether the electron cloud itself exhibits a similar property akin to classical objects' angular momentum.

Specifically, I am interested in whether the electron cloud could exhibit a type of angular momentum analogous to classical objects' spin, rather than the spin of individual particles within it. Can we consider the point of highest probability within the cloud as a pseudo "center of mass" and define an axis through it, around which the cloud could hypothetically spin?

In classical mechanics, objects can have two types of angular momentum: orbital angular momentum, as seen in celestial bodies orbiting around each other, and spin angular momentum, such as the Earth rotating around its center axis. Could the electron cloud possess a form of intrinsic angular momentum similar to the latter?

I am curious about the physical basis for why the electron cloud might or might not exhibit such a property. If not, what are the fundamental differences between classical objects and the quantum description of electron clouds that prevent the cloud from having its own angular momentum?

Thank you for any insights or explanations provided.

Comment: Yes, $|\vec{L}| = \sqrt{l(l+1)}\hbar$ this is the orbital angular momentum of an electrons wave function as a function of the quantum number l which, differs classically by being quantized. This  relation can can be found by solving the eigen value equation for the L^2 operator(angular momentum squared operator) and showing that solutions to the schrodinger equation satisfy the eigen value equation for certain potentials, ie the central potential in the hydrogen atom